# Please help me to solve error in GridView

Tags: c#

Can someone help me solving GridView error:

I have a `List<Person>` and I bind to `dataGridView1` as

```
dataGridView1.DataSource=list;
```

Then I do, where I am getting error

```
DataTable dt=(DataTable)DataGridView1.DataSource //Error here Please help me!!!
```

Comment: What's the error? And what sort application is it.. e.g webforms, wpf, winform?

Comment: Did you not set the List<Person> how can it then become a DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Conn
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address {get; set;}

        public Conn(string n, string a)
        {
            Name = n;
            Address = a;
        }

    }


private static List<Conn> coList = new List<Conn>();
//add stuff to list
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = coList;
DataGrid.DataSource = bs;
```

Working code for Windows Forms Application